# Call multiple p:ajax in order

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, synchronous

Lets say I have

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...
    <f:selectItem ... />
    <f:selectItems .../>
    <p:ajax .../> // call A
    <p:ajax .../> // call B
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**How to make call B execute only after call A is done?**

Using p:remoteCommand did not help as I am getting javaScript error that function `updateTableDiv` is undefined

[How to use p:ajax to update several components in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488162/how-to-use-pajax-to-update-several-components-in-order/15489652#answer-15501395)

```
<p:ajax ... update="pieChartDiv" oncomplete="updateTableDiv()" />
...
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTableDiv" update="tableDiv" />
```

Comment: Answers should be in answers, not in edits of the questions

Comment: Hm... wasn't it 24 hours before you could answer your own question...

Comment: Might be, still then, answers do not belong in questions. Then just wait 24h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...
    <f:selectItem ... />
    <f:selectItems .../>
    <p:ajax .../> // call A
    <p:remoteCommand ... />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How it needed to be:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...
    <f:selectItem ... />
    <f:selectItems .../>
    <p:ajax .../> // call A
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:remoteCommand ... />
```